# Need guidance my visual basic app install

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation

Ok so as a complete noob when it comes to databases, I recently created a database in mysql with a visual studio 2010 front end. I wrote the connection strings and the application ran flawlessly on my machine. However, when I go to publish -> install the application on another machine, the install works but the app does not. It does not recognize the database. I think this is due to the fact that I did not set up a data connection via the database explorer in visual studio. So I go and try and set up that connection using various guides that I have read online. So I click the "connect to database" button via the database explorer and my data sources appear. However, the one that the guides are using does not "Mysql database". So I choose the next best thing "Microsoft SQL Server Database File". Thinking this will work, I try to locate the .mdf file it is looking for. I can not find this file. My question is: Do I need to choose "Mysql database" and if so, how do I go about getting it to appear? I believe this is the last step I need to take before this application will be able to be installed on another machine but I could be wrong.

Edit - Adding code by request.

```
Dim MySqlConn As MySqlConnection
MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
MySqlConn.ConnectionString() = "server=localhost;" _
                             & "user id=root;" _
                             & "password=Password;" _
                             & "database=Database"
Try
    MySqlConn.Open()
    MySqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
       MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)
    Else
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End If
Finally

MySqlConn.Dispose()
```

Edit 2 - My issue is now resolved

Comment: Two things, could you list the code where you setup the connection? And did you run this program in debug first before doing the install?

Comment: Is MySQL installed on a server?  If installed locally, then you'd have to install MySQL on the target PC, too.

Comment: @sparkysword I have listed the code for the connection. I also ran the program in debug mode before doing the install. If it is any help, when I run the install, the message "Unknown database 'databasename'"

Comment: Ah, then it sounds like your problem is closer to what @CMKanode is saying. Might want to make sure your target PC has that database set up.

Comment: @CMKanode it is installed on the target PC, Does it need to be installed on a server if there is only going to be one user using the application?

Comment: If the database is for the *local* app only, you may want to consider using Sqlite or MS Sql Compact.  Those can be embedded *with* the app.  You can use NuGet to install those packages directly in your project.  Just guessing, but MySQL might be overkill for this app.

Comment: Did you setup the client's MySQL DB the same as your development one?  If it is saying "unknown database", then you may not have set up the database in MySQL.  Are you running any setup scripts?

Comment: @CMKanode I do not have any setup scripts. I was under the impression that as long as I incorporated the Mysql.dll, with the installer that I would not have to do any sort of database set up.

Comment: Setup the client MySQL installation to mirror your development environment:  create the needed database.  create the needed tables.  Add any data that you may need.  You can probably script the scheme and data from your development database, and run it on the client.

Comment: @CMKanode Thanks for all your input, I was able to get the application installed.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll type up an answer based on all the comments, so that we can have something of an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer is based off of the comments under the question.  I just wanted to have an answer in place.

The application was deployed to the client machine.  In addition, MySQL was installed on the client machine, too.  However, the application did not contain any setup script or method to create/initialize the required database and data tables.

**Corrective Action:**
As an immediate fix, manually create the database and tables in MySQL that the application requires.  This will correct the error of unknown database.

**Other Suggestions**
MySQL may be an overkill for this application.  And having a dependency on MySQL does limit the portability of the application.  In my opinion, a portable database such as SQLite or MS SQL Compact would be better choices.  Either of those can be included in the project, and compiled with the application.  **Note:** Still, one would need to create a method to initialize the database on first run or on install.  Otherwise, the original issue (not finding the database) will still occur.